# Ignoring the hint for a language string in nopcommerce

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, nopcommerce

So in nopcommerce in my model I have something like this:

```
[NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Catalog.Products.SpecificationAttributes.Fields.Verified")]
public bool? Verified { get; set; }
```

In my logs it gives me a warning like this:

> Resource string (admin.catalog.products.specificationattributes.fields.verified.hint) is not found. Language ID = 1

How would I go about ignoring the hint?
I tried adding a blank resource string > admin.catalog.products.specificationattributes.fields.verified.hint
But it tells me it must have a value.
I figure it must be something easy but couldn't find anything on google.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is something that you need to bother about. Though if you don't want to add into logs, you need to customize the solution and to prevent hint logs into table.

Comment: Hey @Div I added answer, thanks for your help though. I think it's good to leave hints so you can see where resource strings may be missed with dev work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it turns out if your seeing that error in the logs it's because in the admin panel that resource display name is used, I actually thought it wasn't.
So I just put something in there as the hint value.

```
admin.catalog.products.specificationattributes.fields.verified.hint "Has the product been verified, if so tick this box"
```

From my research I don't think it's possible to hide hint values.